# How to handle all exceptions in one place for several endpoints?

Tags: python, rest, exception, dry

I'm using pynic framework to handle my APIs endpoints, but I guess this would be the same logic with Flask or Django.

I've got a few endpoints, and I was wondering if there were anyway to handle all the exceptions at the same place.

For instance:

```
class Pnorm(Handler):
    def post(self):

        logger = logging.getLogger(constants.loggerName)
        template_exception = "Exception {0} in class {1} ({2})."

        try:
            myJson = DoThings()
            return myJson

        except HTTP_400 as e:
            logger.critical(message)
            raise e
        except Exception as e:
            # unknown exception raise 500
            logger.critical(message)
            raise HTTP_500(message)
```

Is there anyway I can make all my endpoints handle the exceptions the same way or do I hacve to repeat my "exception block" at the end of each point ?
(I don't mean in the same class only but through the project.)

Cheers,
Julien

Edited:
My main class:

```
class app(WSGI):
    DataStructureHelper.set_dsh()
    setup_logging.setup_logging(logger_name=constants.loggerName, console_level=logging.INFO)

    routes = [
        ('/allocator', Allocator()),
        ('/data/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)', InstrumentData()),
        ('/pnorm', Pnorm()),
        ('/portfolios')
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the right approach would be decorators, since it fits the needs perfectly. Following is working piece of code w.r.t flask.

A word of caution is you need return the control back to handlers from decorator.

```
from functools import wraps
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)
def http_error_codes(method_name):
    @wraps(method_name)
    def handle_exceptions(*args):
        try:
            print("Inside the exceptions")
            return method_name(*args)
        except Exception as e:
            print("HAHAHAHA")
            raise e
    return handle_exceptions

def do_the_login():
    return "Testing is fun"

def show_the_login_form():
    raise ValueError('The day is too frabjous.')

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@http_error_codes
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return do_the_login()
    else:
        return show_the_login_form()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle all the exceptions in a single place, you can keep an general exceptional block like as follows..

```
try:
    #Code part may give error
except Exception:
   #If error what to do..
```

Here Exception is the General class, which will handle all exceptions irrespective of the error.

Comment: Thanks, That's what I usually do, but here, i'm not sure where to put it. I've edited my initial post and added my main class